# Full path of class name file in php autoloader

Tags: php, autoloader, spl-autoload-register

I build my own autoload function, its prototype is:

```
function example_Autoloader($class_name)
```

After that I register her in this way:

```
spl_autoload_register('example_Autoloader');
```

Question is if can I calculate the full path of `$class_name`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly you can not.
I can recommend you to use the filename when creating your autoloader.